# Heroku + Gmail SMTP + PHP mail in popup contact form

Tags: php, ajax, email, heroku, gmail

Hello I am trying to make a pop up contact form that send mail on heroku and gmail as it's mail server here is a [link](http://sivi29y-bitstarter-s-mooc.herokuapp.com/). the popup part is ok but it cannot send the mail help me please find the problems. The idea is to use gmail as the third side server for heroku which i understand is possible. thanks for any help

the index.html file
js part

```
 <!-- contact form pop -->
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("input#submit").click(function(){
             $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "process.php", //process to mail
                         data: $('form.contact_body').serialize(),
                                 success: function(msg){
                                 $("#thanks").html(msg) //hide button and show thank you
                                 $("#contact").modal('hide'); //hide popup
                                 },
                                 error: function(){
                                        alert("sorry the message could not be send");
                                 }
                               });
                  });
             });
  </script>
```

markup part

```
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="contact_body" name="contact_body">
          <label class="label" for="form_name">Your Name</label><br>
          <input type="text" name="form_name" id="form_name" class="input-xlarge"><br>
          <label class="label" for="form_email">Your E-mail</label><br>
          <input type="form_email" name="form_email" class="input-xlarge"><br>
          <label class="label" for="form_msg">Enter a Message</label><br>
          <textarea name="form_msg" class="input-xlarge"></textarea>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
         <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Nah.</a>
       </div>
     </div>
```

process.php file

```
<?php

// Pear Mail Library
require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<from.gmail.com>';
$to = '<to.yahoo.com>';
subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => '465',
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => 'moviply.tv@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'pass'
));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
 } else {
echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}


/*
$myemail = 'moviply.tv@gmail.com';
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks!      Here   is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
echo "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$name."<br>";
echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>";
echo "<stong>Message:</strong> ".$message."<br>";


$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

My first guesses: the $to/$from addresses at the top of process.php should be (a) real messages, and will (b) likely fail if the from address is not your own Email address so you're not sending spam as someone else.

The SendGrid libraries are pretty simple to use, but again should have a real 'from' address (likely your own), otherwise when SG delivers to your gmail account, it doesn't end up as spam for coming from some unknown address over and over.

(disclosure, I work for SendGrid)

Comment: Thanks. SG is temporary solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check your Gmail account configuration, please find the checklist at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45477794/1891220

> You have to check two important things when you want to send emails via Gmail smtp:
>
> 1. Your apps configuration:
>
>    - host: `smtp.gmail.com`
>    - port: `587` or `465` (587 for tls, 465 for ssl)
>    - protocol: `tls` or `ssl`
>    - user: `YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com`
>    - password: `YOUR_PASSWORD`
> 2. The given Gmail account settings:
>
>    - If you've turned on 2-Step Verification for your account, you might need to enter an [App password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en#ASPs).
>    - Without 2-Step Verification:
>
>      1. Allow [less secure apps access](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) to your account.
>      2. Visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with your Gmail username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that gmail is blocking this service currently and there must be another route for simpler solution. unless you are using google apps (the price now is 5$ per month).

The server did give a 200 (ok) answer with heroku own Sendgrid add-on. So a temporary solution is to use send-grid and migrate it to a something else in the future if necessary as it still not fully tested by me.