# Gmail not receiving ActionMailer Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail, actionmailer

So I'm building my portfolio right now and I want to send an actual email to my gmail in development and production, using ActionMailer.

I have configured my development.rb in a way such that if a user enters the contact form, and submit it ActionMailer would send an email to my gmail account; problem is, my gmail shows no email coming from the contact form even though logs says that the email was sent successfully.
Things I've tried:

1. Change gmail setting to accept less secure apps
2. Change smtp to sendmail
3. moved the whole smtp/sendmail configs to dev/prod.rb instead of smtp.rb
4. change gmail addresses

Funny thing is, it used to work both in prod & development env but after a couple of hours of not working on it, these stopped working. Please give me advise as far as how I can fix this.

development.rb

```
  # MAiler
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'localhost', port: '3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  #send email in dev mode
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors= true

  ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_EMAIL"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

smtp.rb
None at the moment, but used to be

```
  ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_EMAIL"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Production.rb

```
# MAiler
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host:'www.domainname.com' } #domainname hidden 
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  #send email in dev mode
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors= true
  # config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
```

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def contact_email(contact)
    @contact = contact
      # default from: "#{@contact.email}"
      mail(from: "#{@contact.email}", to: "email@gmail.com", subject: "#{@contact.subject}")
  end
end
```

.env

```
GMAIL_EMAIL=email.com
GMAIL_PASSWORD=#hiddenbcofsecurity
```

Any insights will be appreciated. Also if additional info is needed to let me know.
Thanks.

EDIT: I will post the logs of what the terminal is showing upon submitting the form.

Development:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2019-12-19 00:22:29 +0900
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2UYC+mGR9c/S1obBYFyBxZ76vfXUQijnQsfz8C9BeqwgeUshNV/ARlHDLvaIVripK1sRTeuXjQGRg6n0+zKS4g==", "contact"=>{"full_name"=>"Bob Marley", "email"=>"bobmarley@nifty.com", "subject"=>"dev modde", "message"=>"hi"}, "commit"=>"SEND"}
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:8
  Contact Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("full_name", "email", "message", "created_at", "updated_at", "subject") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["full_name", "Bob Marley"], ["email", "bobmarley@nifty.com"], ["message", "hi"], ["created_at", "2019-12-18 15:22:29.134945"], ["updated_at", "2019-12-18 15:22:29.134945"], ["subject", "dev modde"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:8
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:8
  Rendering contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.4ms)
ContactMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 42.8ms
Sent mail to mygmail@gmail.com (34.0ms)
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 00:22:29 +0900
From: bobmarley@nifty.com
To: mygmail@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5dfa44353062c_2c493fc67aa1acf4626e0@taiseis-mbp.lan.mail>
Subject: dev modde
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7b

it

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    hi
  </body>
</html>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects
Completed 302 Found in 99ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

In production (heroku logs):

```
2019-12-18T15:26:07.321077+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.320977 #4]  INFO -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f] Started POST "/contacts" for 14.11.35.130 at 2019-12-18 15:26:07 +0000
2019-12-18T15:26:07.322013+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.321958 #4]  INFO -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f] Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2019-12-18T15:26:07.322129+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.322076 #4]  INFO -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QKe+3gNQhLKsvXoSisk4X40MZUg8+kCDB51wFKjTZr6FtyTHgAcN8HN6jwwLjpQyb/RR63R5GTYEIkFX5yKXww==", "contact"=>{"full_name"=>"Bob Marley", "email"=>"bobmarley@nifty.com", "subject"=>"prod mode", "message"=>"pro mode"}, "commit"=>"SEND"}
2019-12-18T15:26:07.325362+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.325304 #4] DEBUG -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f]    (0.8ms)  BEGIN
2019-12-18T15:26:07.327780+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.327723 #4] DEBUG -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f]   Contact Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("full_name", "email", "message", "created_at", "updated_at", "subject") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["full_name", "Bob Marley"], ["email", "bobmarley@nifty.com"], ["message", "pro mode"], ["created_at", "2019-12-18 15:26:07.325667"], ["updated_at", "2019-12-18 15:26:07.325667"], ["subject", "prod mode"]]
2019-12-18T15:26:07.329643+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.329591 #4] DEBUG -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f]    (1.6ms)  COMMIT
2019-12-18T15:26:07.333855+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.333795 #4]  INFO -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f]   Rendering contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
2019-12-18T15:26:07.334327+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.334271 #4]  INFO -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f]   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.4ms)
2019-12-18T15:26:07.335088+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.335025 #4] DEBUG -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f] ContactMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 5.1ms
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338215+00:00 app[web.1]: **sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found**
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338580+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.338497 #4]  INFO -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f] **Sent mail to mygmail@gmail.com** (3.3ms)
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338659+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.338591 #4] DEBUG -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f] Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2019 15:26:07 +0000
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338661+00:00 app[web.1]: From: bobmarley@nifty.com
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338662+00:00 app[web.1]: To: mygmail@gmail.com
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338664+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <5dfa450f5202a_42b157c94faf411871@f450c424-ae43-4fd2-8009-51ce04ea4d9f.mail>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338665+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: prod mode
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338666+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338667+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338669+00:00 app[web.1]: charset=UTF-8
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338670+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338671+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338672+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338673+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338674+00:00 app[web.1]: <head>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338676+00:00 app[web.1]: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338677+00:00 app[web.1]: <style>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338678+00:00 app[web.1]: /* Email styles need to be inline */
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338679+00:00 app[web.1]: </style>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338680+00:00 app[web.1]: </head>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338680+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338681+00:00 app[web.1]: <body>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338682+00:00 app[web.1]: pro mode
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338683+00:00 app[web.1]: </body>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338684+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338685+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-12-18T15:26:07.338964+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-12-18T15:26:07.338914 #4]  INFO -- : [775341a7-6c37-4b93-8b4a-65afaec7426f] Redirected to mydomain
```

No errors were found aside from 
**sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found**
which is weird because i added the sendmail gem and executed bundle install.

Comment: I think your domain could be, at least, one of your issues.  That should be the domain of the website, not `gmail.com`.  I do not think that will be taken as valid.  Also, are you seeing any errors in your log file?

Comment: @RockwellRice thanks for your comment. I changed the domain name to localhost:3000 in dev env and mydomain name in prod env respectively however it also does not seem to be working. Also, no errors were found (log posted in main post).

Comment: Is your production site hosted on Heroku by chance?  It has been a while since I set this up, I rememeber having an issue with gmail and heroku when I did try this before and that ended up pushing me to using an email service.

Comment: @RockwellRice Yes I'm hosting my site on heroku. 
I see.. what alternatives would you recommend? Also by email service do you mean like mailchimp, mailgun, etc?

Comment: Not sure, I think this was the question that helped me get going, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244309/heroku-not-sending-email-with-gmail-smtp . Of maybe https://blog.heroku.com/tech_sending_email_with_gmail