# Why routes created by "php artisan ui:auth" cannot send emails in Heroku but work fine in dev env?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

[This is my app developed using Laravel](http://desolate-depths-67569.herokuapp.com)

If you try to reigster an account, after you fill the form and click the `register` button, an `500 server  error` will appear.

And the heroku logs are:

```
2020-05-15T21:43:50.724460+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.152.193.4 - - [15/May/2020:21:43:48 +0000] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 1558 "http://desolate-depths-67569.herokuapp.com/register" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;
 x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36
```

It doesn't seem helpful...

And it works fine in dev env.

Here is the [github link](https://github.com/powerseed/Laravel-Forum) of my project.

I used the build-in command `php artisan ui:auth` to create the register and email verification functionalities.

Could anyone give me some hints about why the `500 server error` occurs on Heroku please?

Thanks in advance!

Edited:
I believe the db is set up correctly, as this is the info about the seeding I did on heroku:

```
~ $ php artisan db:seed
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes

Seeding: UsersTableSeeder
Seeded:  UsersTableSeeder (0.12 seconds)
Seeding: TopicsTableSeeder
Seeded:  TopicsTableSeeder (0.81 seconds)
Seeding: ReplySeeder
Seeded:  ReplySeeder (9.02 seconds)
Database seeding completed successfully.
```

And you can use email `summer@example.com` and password `password` to login.

Edited:
As @Oludotun pointed out, the problem should be in the email-sending process, since it is the very next step after clicking on the `register button. And the error also occurs when resetting the password, where an email also needs to be sent.
Here is how I configured my email-sending process:

```
APP_URL:           http://desolate-depths-67569.herokuapp.com/
IS_IN_HEROKU:      true
MAIL_DRIVER:       smtp
MAIL_ENCRYPTION:   SSL
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: XXX@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME:    LaravelForum
MAIL_HOST:         smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD:     XXX
MAIL_PORT:         465
MAIL_USERNAME:     XXX@gmail.com
```

Any ideas? It works good locally...

Comment: Did you setup a database and run migrations?

Comment: @Oludotun Yes, you can see the posts and replies. If I didn't, they wouldn't show up. And I have updated this post to include the heroku info about the seeding I did.

Comment: If you're using a free dyno, then it's possible you've reach the 10K row limit.

Comment: @Oludotun  Sry I stated it wrong. You can login using email `summer@example.com` and password `password`. So I think the User table is set up correctly. The error only occurs when registering.

Comment: I think the problem is in the Register Controller, verify if the protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME; is a valid route

Comment: @Oludotun In `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php`, `public const HOME = '/';` It is a URL I think, not a route. And it is valid since it just directs to the home page. And it works fine locally..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213979/discussion-between-oludotun-and-powerseed).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It is because I didn't configure the Gmail email service properly.

According to Gex' answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244309/heroku-not-sending-email-with-gmail-smtp), I was missing the very last step:

> Visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and sign in with your Gmail username and password.

Thanks to @Oludotun for helping me narrow the possible causes.